# What does this short snippet of C code do

Tags: c, pointers

Could someone explain what this code does

```
size = *(int *)data;        // size of string plus header word
off = (size + 3) & ~3;
chan = *(int *)(data + off);
data[size] = '\0';      // zero terminate
```

I think it's got something to do with making the data a multiple of 4?

Comment: What is the type of data? Array of char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `data` is a `char*`...

```
size = *(int *)data;        // size of string plus header word
```

`data` is interpreted as a pointer-to-`int`, then dereferenced and assigned to `size`.

```
off = (size + 3) & ~3;
```

This rounds `size` upwards to the nearest multiple of 4, and assigns to `off`.

```
chan = *(int *)(data + off);
```

The value for `chan` apparently resides `off` bytes from `data`.

```
data[size] = '\0';      // zero terminate
```

That one is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This line casts `data` to a pointer to an `int` and dereferences the pointer and stores the value in an variable named `size`:

```
size = *(int *)data;
```

This line gets the smallest multiple of four greater than or equal to `size` and assigns the result to the variable `off`:

```
off = (size + 3) & ~3;
```

This line gets an `int` value offset `sizeof(char) * off` bytes from the pointer `data` and stores the result in `chan`:

```
chan = *(int *)(data + off);
```

This line null-terminates the block of memory:

```
data[size] = '\0';
```

So it looks like `size` is a block of memory wherein the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of `data` can be thought of as an `int` indicating the `size` of the block of memory. Apparently there is meaningful data at `data` plus `sizeof(char) * smallestmultipleoffourlargerthan(size)`. Without knowing details of `data` this is the best we can say.

Comment: Thanks Jason, you have been most helpful

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jason's answer, it looks like this code is pulling apart the contents of a data structure whose beginning is stored at `data`.  The data structure that is stored there seems to be formatted something like this:

```
{
  int size;
  char data[(size + 3) & ~3];
  int chan;
}
```